# Active css menu tabs

Tags: css, codeigniter

I've been reading from this link [Active menu tabs with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511558/active-menu-tabs-with-codeigniter), and it works but how about if the link like this `domain.com/mycontroller/myfunction/id`

for example `menu A` -> `domanin.com/A/a/1`, `menu A` -> `domanin.com/A/b/1`, etc. The highlight active class is on the 'A' controller.

thank you

**edited**

below is my template view code

```
 <?php foreach ($menu as $row): ?>
 <li <?php if($this->uri->uri_string(2) == url_title($row->menu,'/detail_product/',TRUE)):?>class="active"<?php endif;?>><?php echo anchor('/'.$row->link,$row->menu); ?></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

here my controller code

```
public function index()
{
    $data['content'] = 'home/garagebox';
    $data['menu'] = $this->auction_model->load_menu();

    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}
```

my menu look like this,

Home | Auction | News

and I have product when I choose one it will direct to this link `http://domain.com/index.php/auction/detail_product/1` because this link it's under Auction menu so on Auction menu it's should be highlight

Comment: I'm not sure I follow to a 100%, but if you still have `index.php` in your adress, perhaps you need to look at `uri_string(3)` instead?

Comment: how does your `$row->link` and `$row->menu` look like?

Comment: @air4x I don't know what your mean?

Comment: @danneth it's same, nothing change anything..

Comment: Inside the `foreach` do `echo $row->link.' - '. $row->menu;` and show us the result.

Answer (score 0):

link 1 | link 2 | ...

First of all you need to set a variable in your controller file like.

```
 $data['selected_menu'] = 'link1';
 $this->load->view('your view file',$data); //and send $data variable to your view file.
```

In view file you simply, check the values:

```
 if($selected_menu == 'link1')
      //highlight link.
```

Same as all controllers i.e. methods/functions.

Comment: You have some problem in codeIgnitor project. please download http://codeigniter.com/download.php and apply the code.

One more thing, Please upload your controller and view file.

Comment: I think my codeigniter project fine..I already edit my question